# How to list 5 most view nodes without using the Statistic module?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I am trying to create a view/block of the most viewed node without using a module if possible.

If it's not possible, is it possible to do it without using the statistic module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple and best solution which work with views is [node view count](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount). Which works with views and play around it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the [Node view count](https://drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) modules (already mentioned in another answer), here are some other modules that might be a possible fit:

- [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) (disclosure: I'm the maintainer of it).

  Comes with a set of **Visitors Reports**, such as:

  - User activity report (hits, nodes, comments).
  - A *Visitor* tab that is added to each node, with details about Referrer, Date, User, IP address, User agent.
- [Better Statistics](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_statistics), here's a quote from its project page:

  > ... introduces a Statistics API, allowing developers and contributed modules a way to collect, limit, and route custom access statistics and data.